# Can anyone please help me to solve this? No equation number is appearing for this code

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}

  R_{SU_1}^{(e)} =

    \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{ln2}\bigg[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,max
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Does removing the empty lines help?

Comment: Why did you tag this biblatex? Can someone edit the proper tags please?

Comment: Remove all `\nonumber` commands and the empty lines in the `equation` environment.

Comment: I have removed the empty lines. Still, the problem is not solved.

Comment: If you can't solve the problem with the information provided in the answers, please consider updating your question with the following: (1) a fully compilable example *document* that shows the problem, not just a code snippet (a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)), (2) a description or screenshot of the output you get at the moment from running the exact code of your example document, and (3) a description of the output you wish to see instead.

Comment: If one of the answers did solve your problem, please consider accepting it to show it did. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Why making the question even more unclear by removing random parts of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is too long to fit with standard margins, and you have to split it.  To make it easier, I loadd the `geometry` package to have more sensible margins (if you don't use margin notes). I propose one of these two layouts, with a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\MoveEqLeft R_{SU_1}^{(e)} = \frac{1}{\ln2}\times \\
    & \begin{cases}
     \biggl[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s \max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,\max}}} \mathrlap{\bigl [ye^yEi(-y)+1\bigr] \biggr]} \\ & \text{if $x = 1$ i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} = \sigma^2$}\\
     \biggl[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}\mathrlap{\bigl[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)-e^yEi(-y)\bigr]\biggr]} \\ & \text{if $x \neq 1$, i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} \neq \sigma^2$}
          \end{cases}
\end{split}
          \label{u1}
\end{equation}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 R_{SU_1}^{(e)} = \frac{1}{\ln2} \biggl[ & {-}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s \max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu) \\[-1ex]
    & +x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,\max}}}\times\begin{cases}
     \bigl [ye^yEi(-y)+1\bigr] \biggr] & \text{if $x = 1$ i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} = \sigma^2$}\\
   \bigl[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)-e^yEi(-y)\bigr]\biggr] & \text{if $x \neq 1$, i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} \neq \sigma^2$}
          \end{cases}
\end{split}
          \label{u1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.. The second part is working for me. The first part shows an error. But the second part is enough for me. Thanks again

Comment: Did you load `mathtools` (it is an extension of `amsmath`, so needless to load the latter in this case).

Comment: Yes Sir. Now that is also working. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The formulas in the two branches are quite similar, so I would go for something like one of the following:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent Define
\[
R(x,y,z) = \frac1{\ln2}
\biggl[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}{\bigl[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)+z\bigr]\biggr]}
\]
Then
\begin{equation}\label{E:}
R_{SU_1}^{(e)} =
    \begin{cases*}
       R(x,y,z)&if $x = 1$ i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} = \sigma^2$\\
       R(x,y,-e^yEi(-y))&if $x \neq 1$, i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} \neq \sigma^2$
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\textit{\dotfill or\dotfill}

\noindent Define
\[
R(x) = \frac1{\ln2}
\biggl[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s, \max}}}\biggr]
\]
Then
\begin{equation}\label{E:}
R_{SU_1}^{(e)} =
    \begin{cases*}
       R(x)\bigl[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)+1\bigr]
           &if $x = 1$ i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} = \sigma^2$\\
       R(x)\bigl[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)-e^yE_i(-y)\bigr]
           &if $x \neq 1$, i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} \neq \sigma^2$
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\ln2` and the use of the `cases*` environment from the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Answer (score 0):

Like esdd said in the comments you need to remove the `\nonumber` and the empty lines:

```
\begin{equation}
  R_{SU_1}^{(e)} =
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{1}{ln2}\bigg[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,max}}} [ye^yEi(-y)+1] \bigg] &  \\ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{if $x = 1$ i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} = \sigma^2$}\\
      \frac{1}{ln2}\bigg[ -e^\mu E_i(\mu)+e^{\frac{I \lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,max}}}e^\mu E_i(\mu)+x e^{-\frac{I\lambda_{s,p}}{P_{s,max}}}[e^{xy}Ei(-xy)-e^yEi(-y)] & \\ \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \text{if $x \neq 1$, i.e., $\lambda_{s,p}\alpha I_{th} \neq \sigma^2$}\\
          \end{cases}    
          \label{u1}  
\end{equation}
```

Like `\nonumber` says itself, it will prevent the numbering for the equations